# javascript - automate deletion of comments in a HTML template

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a frontend for sanitize html templates. The templates are posted to an API which not accept some characters for example css comments like

```
 //margin-top: 10px;
 <!-- delete this -->
```

I create a function which transform the template in a array by the \n, and then i go through the array looking for the comments or some characters replacing them. The problem is what when i find some // it can be an URL.

What you recommend me to do?

This is the code.

```
tiny.on('.sanitize-btn', 'click', function(e) {


    const inputToSanitize = document.querySelector('.textarea').value;
    const previewOfHtmlSanitizedAndCompress = document.querySelector('.ui-sanitazer__error-show');

    const lines = inputToSanitize.split('\n');

    for(let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

        if(lines[i].indexOf('//') !== -1 || lines[i].indexOf('<!--') !== -1 || lines[i].indexOf('/*')) {
            lines.splice(i, 1);     
        }
    }

    const newtext = lines.join('\n');

    const finalInput = newtext
                .replace("'", "\'")
                .replace("¿", "\¿")
                .replace("?", "\?")
                .replace("$", "&#36;")
                .replace("!", "&#33");

    previewOfHtmlSanitizedAndCompress.innerHTML = finalInput;
}
```

Comment: @Teemu yes, but some can be in the <head> and other in the body of the html. So i have to delete all the comments.

Comment: Just use a DOM parser, parsing HTML with RegExps is doomed.

Comment: @Teemu Ok, will try!